# Why can't I delay the population of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

I am grabbing all images from the current DOM tree. I display them into my custom unify div and allow the user to select them.

```
var allImgs = $('img');

allImgs.each(function (index) {
    var imgUrl = $(this).attr("src");
    var newImgTag = $('<img></img>');
    newImgTag.attr("src", imgUrl);
    newImgTag.attr("width", "100px");
    newImgTag.attr("height", "100px");

    $("#Image-Grid").append(newImgTag);  // this works

    newImgTag.click(function (event) {
        $('#Selected-Image').empty();
        $('#Selected-Image').append(newImgTag);   // this doesn`t work why????
    });
});
```

I am able to get all image to display into my unify div.
however, when I select one picture from unify div. image will not display properly.

e.g I randomly pick a fashion site.
`http://www.abercrombie.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10901&storeId=10051&langId=-1&categoryId=12266&parentCategoryId=%5bLjava.lang.String%3b%403dc73dc7&topCategoryId=12203&productId=1014475`

When I select one of the pic, I notice that, the src link for the pic is something like this
`/anf/50817/img/global/logo-print.png`

Why can't I display the picture later in the click event?

Comment: `<img/>` it's a self closing tag... `$('<img/>')`

Comment: @elclanrs, thanks... i change to use self closing tag... still not working for me.... -_-!!!

Comment: Are you trying to Lazy Load your images? There's a plugin for that: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newImgTag.click(function (event) {
        $('#Selected-Image').empty();
        $(this).clone().appendTo('#Selected-Image');
});
```

Docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/clone/

---

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

(...) As shown in the discussion for .append(), normally when an element is inserted somewhere in the DOM, it is moved from its old location. So, given the code:

```
$('.hello').appendTo('.goodbye');
```

The resulting DOM structure would be:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="goodbye">
    Goodbye
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To prevent this and instead create a copy of the element, you could write the following:

```
$('.hello').clone().appendTo('.goodbye');
```

This would produce:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">
    Goodbye
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```